# New Line \n Weird Output and Is Not Working PHP 7.1

Tags: php, html, mysqli, sms

I'm trying to send a SMS message and getting different results. I read all the other possibilities and still have not found a solution.

I'm getting 2 different results. One from a variable string the other as a object string from the DB.

First one works as excepted.

```
$body2 = "Bombshell Image with \nSpace in name";
print_r($body2);
```

Output as expected:

```
Output: Bombshell Image with Space in name
```

Second from DB:

```
$body = $res->message;
//$res->message = 
Bombshell Image with \nSpace in name
print($body);
```

Output not the same:

```
Output: Bombshell Image with \nSpace in name
```

I also tried to change the header to text:

```
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
```

When I ran gettype() they both return as string. The field from the MySQL DB is set to text and utf8_unicode_ci.
I'm out of ideas!

Anyone have some thoughts about this?

Comment: So is this about the SMS now, or about perhaps doubly-escaped database contents?

Comment: look at your HTML source; are those on separate lines by any chance? Yet, why are you using `print_r()` in one and then `print()` on the other?

Comment: You’ve actually written “\n” into your database rather than what the escape sequence means. Why? That we can’t say.

Comment: Good catch @FunkFortyNiner Now it prints to the screen the same. Guess I was looking at it to long.

Comment: @mario ...I'm not sure. I still get the same output to SMS message.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working...added this code

```
    $body =  str_replace('\n', "\n", $body);
```

Maybe someone else can explain why that now works.

Comment: `\n` in single quotes doesn't work, it needs to be inside double quotes. That's why what you posted as a solution works ;-)